# wcf service REST POST with a Data Contract or multiple parameters from objective c

Tags: c#, objective-c, wcf, web-services, wcf-data-services

I have a couple of "Post" Operation Contracts in my service that would require receiving multiple parameters. I use Json as the format. Was wondering if

- The parameter expected is a DataContract, how do I create the URI
  coming from objective c? Do I have to specify the UriTemplate? Below
  are the two contracts that I have. the first one handles the **GET**
  which I was able to retrieve on JSON format. My problem is if I want
  to modify and save, I'm not sure how to pass it back to the service.

eg.

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalendarService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Event?eventId={eventId}&consumer={consumer}")]
        Event GetEvent(int eventId, string consumer);


[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        bool UpdateEventDetails(Event event);

}

[DataContract]
public class Event{
  [DataMember]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Notes { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public bool Private { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string Date { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public int AuditedById { get; set; }
}
```

- My next question would be regarding best practices with posts. Should
  I always use a data contract? What if I only wanted to edit/modify 2
  properties on that data contract, do I just pass the values of the
  two properties? Or do I require it to pass the whole data contract
  still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes in the Event class.

Just decorate your interface method with the following attributes

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
```

Comment: but how do i send the message tho? eg. http://localhost:9999/Event.svc/UpdateEventDetails?......

Comment: You can use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to construct the JSON and you can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to test your service.